# "Run" or "Open" exe files from a sharepoint document library

Tags: 2010

So I've managed to get sharepoint to accept exe files in my doc library, by going into central admin and removing it from blocked file-types.

I now need to make a link to an exe file on my sharepoint site, where users can choose to "Run" the exe files. At the moment I only get the option to download and Save when I click the link.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

Simply putting - it is not possible to run the exe without downloading it, it has to be downloaded into local machine then only the exe can be executed

Comment: agreed - generally the browser will handle what to do with the object.

Comment: Well, I've seen it work on a 2007 installation. It should be possible, as it's not sharepoint running it - it's the browser dialog (Open, save, cancel) I'm missing, where open also downloads the file, but automatically opens it right away too (from temp folder)

Answer (score 2):

I'd not recommend teaching users that it's OK to run .exe files from the browser, but if you REALLY want to then you should enabel Permissive as Browser File Handling for the Web Application:

1. Go to Central Admin | Application Management | Manage Web Applications
2. Select the Web Application
3. Click General Settings in the Ribbon
4. Set Permissive as Browser File Handling
5. OK

Answer (score 1):

If you upload the exe in a documentlibrary and map this library to a networkdrive as you can see [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/lystavlen/archive/2011/10/06/how-to-access-a-office-365-document-library-from-windows-explorer.aspx), you can access it as if it was on your local computer.

As long as you use the IE and know the path, you can start the file with some JavaScript and your own startlink:

```
<a href="javascript:LaunchApp()">Launch the executable</a>

<script>
function LaunchApp() {
if (!document.all) {
  alert ("Available only with Internet Explorer.");
  return;
}
var ws = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
ws.Exec("C:\\Windows\\notepad.exe");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Believe it or not, it **IS** actually possible to execute a file (that exists on the user's local machine) from a web page, but it is not a good idea to do this unless it is on your own internal LAN.  Now, I am sure this is a security risk of sorts, but I actually wrote a program that will create custom url protocols that you can use in hyperlinks. To minimize the security risk, there is an optional confirmation prompt.  You have to install and configure the program on the local computer.

I use it on my LAN to provide links that will open windows explorer to folders on the network server.

My [little app is in a zip file, here](http://www.sspxusa.org/goodies/http://www.sspxusa.org/goodies/Protocaller.zip), but you use it at your own risk - be sure to read all of the instructions.

Answer (score 0):

There's a utility called [webrun](http://www.webrunapps.com) which does the job nicely. Beware of security risks as BGM pointed out.