# Launch local application from Sharepoint

Tags: html, launch

On my SharePoint site I want to have a link that will open an application.

Our SharePoint site is on the intranet and every user has this application. Say the application was notepad, how would I go about this?

I have 30 users that would need this functionality so a simple install to users registry would be nice if possible but I would love to hear best practice.

Comment: will the link be to a document (e.g., txt, doc) file or directly to an app (with .exe extension) ?

Comment: It will be to an app, so a .exe extension

Answer (score 1):

To launch an .exe directly (presuming security cleared) -
Link to the .exe directly:

`<a href="file://Foobar/Foobar.exe">Launch Foobar</a>`

This will launch the Foobar app in the Foobar directory.

If using link to the doc only with the file extension .foo that is associated with the Foobar App then use -

`<a href="file://Foofile.foo">Open the Foo document</a>`

Comment: I believe the issue now is clearing security. I have an example code I found:   HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
   alert
      (Default) = "URL:Alert Protocol"
      URL Protocol = ""
      DefaultIcon
         (Default) = "alert.exe,1"
      shell
         open
            command
               (Default) = "C:\Program Files\Alert\alert.exe" "%1"   the app I am trying to open up is incode.

Comment: have you tried the two methods I have mentioned above? if security is an issue in your enterprise - I am not sure if registry settings may be permissible (readily)..

Comment: I just tried to launch an exe and once I click the link it brings me to a new page were it says "page cannot be found" any clues?

Answer (score 0):

Check my answer [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/50166/run-or-open-exe-files-from-a-sharepoint-document-library/114862#114862) you can use WebRun, we are using the Pro version and works great...

Comment: If the question has been answered, flag it as a duplicate.